# Decimals When Subtracting two numbers

Tags: c++

In my program, I have a calculation like

```
a = a * b * c; 

d = f * b* c; // here f and a are same value

d = d - a;
```

When I print the value of d, I got the below result:

> -1.95399e-14

So I set precision and printed the variable by using fixed in cout.

The result is:

> -0.00000000000001954

I wish to print the value of the d and a, before the expression `d = d - a;`

So I changed my code as,

```
cout<< d << endl;

cout<< a << endl;
```

When I include the above two line, The result of variable 'd' after that expression is Exactly '0'

If I didn't print the value of variables 'd' and 'a', It gives the result as `-1.95399e-14;`

In both case, I want the result is '0'. How can I do this? What this cout statment doing?

Comment: Floating point is not exact.  It's as simple as that.  http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Provide the code you use. And as commented before: read about floating points, because computer arithmetic is different than mathematical arithmetic in regards to some aspects (especially precision and floating point arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

Since floating point numbers usually cannot be stored exactly, there are very small errors included in any result from computation on them.  When combined with the optimizer you can get some puzzling results, which your case is one.

In the first case, the compiler keeps the result of `a` and `d` in the FPU registers, which (on x86, in 32 bit code) have more precision than a double.  These long double values are then subtracted, giving you a slight difference.  When you add in the cout call, the `a` and `d` values are written out to memory (both rounding to the same number), then read back into the FPU registers to do the subtraction, which gives you the zero.